# Cannot get sigaction to work

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm trying to create two programs:  A basic socket server, and a client, both of which will run on Linux machines.  The instructions for the server are to set up a socket, accept an incoming client request, set up a handler (for reading a buffer of data) using signal, and enter an infinite sleep loop.  The instructions for the client are to set up a socket, connect to the server, and send a buffer of data.  I'd like to get this working as described for a single client connection before worrying about closing the connection and starting a new one (not sure where these things should be looped yet, and I'm trying to keep this simple.)  I've also learned that signal is deprecated, so I'm attempting to use sigaction as per the example here:

http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/sigaction

Unfortunately, what happens when I run my code is this:

1. Server launches
2. Server sets up socket
3. Server begins listening and blocks on accept (waiting for client)
4. Client launches
5. Client sets up socket
6. Client connects to server
7. Server unblocks
8. Server sets up sigaction
9. Server begins sleeping
10. Client calls write
11. Client appears to write successfully (lord knows where to)
12. Client blocks waiting for bytes read acknowledgement from server
13. Server is still sleeping (sigaction never triggered)

Here is my current code for the server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    // socket, bind
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket, bind, listen, inet_ntoa
#include <netinet/in.h>   // htonl, htons, inet_ntoa
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // inet_ntoa
#include <netdb.h>        // gethostbyname
#include <unistd.h>       // read, write, close
#include <string.h>       // bzero
#include <netinet/tcp.h>  // SO_REUSEADDR
#include <sys/uio.h>      // writev
#include <signal.h>       // sigaction
#include <sys/time.h>     // gettimeofday
#include <unistd.h>       // write
#include <fcntl.h>        // fcntl
#include <iostream>       // cout

using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 1500

// Globals
int nreps;
int nbufs;
int newSd;

// Read all the data from the client and output how long it took
void readFromClient(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    cout << "readFromClient triggered!" << endl;

    /*
    // Set up asynchronous communication
    int fd = siginfo->si_fd;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);
    */

    // Declare data buffer
    char databuf[BUFSIZE];

    // Record start time
    struct timeval theTime;
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int startTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Keep reading until the buffer is full
    int nRead = 0;
    /*
    while((nRead += read(newSd, databuf, BUFSIZE - nRead)) < BUFSIZE)
    {
        cout << "nRead now: " << nRead << endl;
    }
    */

    // For testing single byte read
    cout << "Reading a byte... " << endl;
    char bytebuf[1];
    read(newSd, bytebuf, 1);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Record finish time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int finishTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the receiving time
    int receiveTime = finishTime - startTime;

    // Display the receiving time
    cout << "data-receiving time = " << receiveTime << " usec" << endl;

    // Tell the client how much data was read
    cout << "Writing amount read... " << endl;
    write(newSd, (void*)nRead, 4);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Close the socket
    cout << "Closing socket... " << endl;
    close(newSd);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Exit the program
    cout << "Exiting!" << endl;
    exit(0);
    cout << "Why are you still here?" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Server is running!" << endl;

    // Store command line arguments
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nreps = atoi(argv[2]);
    int nbufs = atoi(argv[3]);
    cout << "port: " << port << endl;
    cout << "nreps: " << nreps << endl;
    cout << "nbufs: " << nbufs << endl;

    // Declare a socket
    sockaddr_in acceptSockAddr;
    memset((char*)&acceptSockAddr, '\0', sizeof(acceptSockAddr));
    acceptSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Address Family Internet
    acceptSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    acceptSockAddr.sin_port = htons(port); // convert host byte-order

    // Open a stream-oriented socket
    int serverSd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Signal OS to reuse this port once server closes
    const int on = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&on, sizeof(int));

    // Bind socket to local address
    bind(serverSd, (sockaddr*)&acceptSockAddr, sizeof(acceptSockAddr));

    // Instruct OS to listen for up to 5 clients
    listen(serverSd, 5);

    // Declare a new socket
    sockaddr_in newSockAddr;
    socklen_t newSockAddrSize = sizeof(newSockAddr);
    int newSd;

    // Set up signal handler for IO from client
    struct sigaction action;  
    memset(&action, '\0', sizeof(action));
    action.sa_sigaction = &readFromClient;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    //fcntl(newSd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO); // Fixes problem with si_fd
    if(sigaction(SIGIO, &action, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    // sleep forever
    cout << "Sleeping..." << endl;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Waiting for client... " << endl;
        newSd = accept(serverSd, (sockaddr*)&newSockAddr, &newSockAddrSize);
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

        cout << "Switching to asynchronous communication... " << endl;
        fcntl(newSd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
        fcntl(newSd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

        cout << "Resuming sleep... " << endl;
        sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my current code for the client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    // socket, bind
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket, bind, listen, inet_ntoa
#include <netinet/in.h>   // htonl, htons, inet_ntoa
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // inet_ntoa
#include <netdb.h>        // gethostbyname
#include <unistd.h>       // read, write, close
#include <string.h>       // bzero
#include <netinet/tcp.h>  // SO_REUSEADDR
#include <sys/uio.h>      // writev
#include <signal.h>       // sigaction
#include <sys/time.h>     // gettimeofday
#include <unistd.h>       // write
#include <fcntl.h>        // fcntl
#include <iostream>       // cout

using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 1500
#define SIZEOFINT 4

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Client is running!" << endl;

    // Store commmand line arguments
    int server_port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nreps = atoi(argv[2]);
    int nbufs = atoi(argv[3]);
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[4]);
    const char* server_name = argv[5];
    int testType = atoi(argv[6]);
    cout << "server_port: " << server_port << endl;
    cout << "nreps: " << nreps << endl;
    cout << "nbufs: " << nbufs << endl;
    cout << "bufsize: " << bufsize << endl;
    cout << "server_name: " << server_name << endl;
    cout << "testType: " << testType << endl;

    // Check to ensure proper buffer count/sizes
    if(nbufs * bufsize != BUFSIZE)
    {
        cout << "nbufs times bufsize must equal " << BUFSIZE << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if(testType < 1 || testType > 3)
    {
        cout << "test type must be 1, 2, or 3" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Create buffers
    char databuf[nbufs][bufsize];

    // Retrieve hostent structure
    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname(server_name);

    // Declare socket structure
    sockaddr_in sendSockAddr;
    memset((char*)&sendSockAddr, '\0', sizeof(sendSockAddr));
    sendSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Address Family Internet
    sendSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*host->h_addr_list));
    sendSockAddr.sin_port = htons(server_port);  // convert host byte-order

    // Open stream-oriented socket
    int clientSd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Connect socket to server
    cout << "Connecting socket to server... " << endl;
    int code = connect(clientSd, (sockaddr*)&sendSockAddr, sizeof(sendSockAddr));
    cout << "Connection result: " << code << endl;

    // Record start time
    struct timeval theTime;
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int startTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Conduct tests
    for(int i = 0; i < nreps; i++)
    {
        switch(testType)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                // Multiple write test
                cout << "Running multiple write test" << endl;
                for(int j = 0; j < nbufs; j++)
                {
                    cout << "Writing buffer " << j << "... " << endl;
                    write(clientSd, databuf[j], bufsize);
                    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
                }
                cout << "Finished multiple write test" << endl;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                // Vector write test
                cout << "Running vector write test" << endl;
                struct iovec vector[nbufs];
                for(int j = 0; j < nbufs; j++)
                {
                    vector[j].iov_base = databuf[j];
                    vector[j].iov_len = bufsize;
                }
                cout << "Writing vector... " << endl;
                writev(clientSd, vector, nbufs);
                cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
                cout << "Finished vector write test" << endl;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                // Single write test
                cout << "Running single write test" << endl;

                /*
                cout << "Writing... ";
                write(clientSd, databuf, nbufs * bufsize);
                cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
                */

                // For testing single byte write
                cout << "writing a byte..." << endl;
                char singleByte[1];
                write(clientSd, singleByte, 1);
                cout << "wrote a byte!" << endl;

                cout << "Finished single write test" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    // Record finish time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int finishTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the sending time
    int sendTime = finishTime - startTime;

    // Receive number of bytes read from server
    int nReads;
    cout << "reading nReads from server... " << endl;
    read(clientSd, (void*)nReads, SIZEOFINT);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Record read time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int readTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the round-trip time
    int roundTime = readTime - startTime;

    // Display data sending statistics
    cout << "Test " << testType << ": data-sending time = " << sendTime;
    cout << " usec, round-trip time = " << roundTime << " usec, # reads = ";
    cout << nReads << endl;

    // Close the socket
    cout << "Closing the socket... " << endl;
    close(clientSd);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    cout << "Exiting!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've spent around 14 hours troubleshooting this already, and tried a number of things before coming here:

- Using SIGTERM instead of SIGIO
- Re-arranging the order of operations so the sigaction is set up prior to accepting an incoming connection
- Using fcntl inside the triggered function instead of inside the sleep loop
- Using the field descriptor from the siginfo_t structure passed into the triggered function
- Using the sa_handler instead of setting the flags for sa_siginfo (so siginfo_t is not passed)
- Not calling fcntl at all
- Switching the servers that these programs are running on
- Switching the ports that these programs are using
- Calling everything before the sleep loop

At this point my instructor is telling me to use the deprecated signal method instead, but that seems like a poor solution.  Surely siginfo is common practice these days, and using it should not have to be this difficult?  Any suggestions on things to try would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to read the `signal(7)` man page. And you should learn more about multiplexing syscalls like `poll(2)` (or the older `select(2)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing references to newSockAddr with acceptSockAddr.  Here is the current code, now malfunctioning in new and terrific ways!:

server.cpp:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    // socket, bind
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket, bind, listen, inet_ntoa
#include <netinet/in.h>   // htonl, htons, inet_ntoa
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // inet_ntoa
#include <netdb.h>        // gethostbyname
#include <unistd.h>       // read, write, close
#include <string.h>       // bzero
#include <netinet/tcp.h>  // SO_REUSEADDR
#include <sys/uio.h>      // writev
#include <signal.h>       // sigaction
#include <sys/time.h>     // gettimeofday
#include <unistd.h>       // write
#include <fcntl.h>        // fcntl
#include <iostream>       // cout

using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 1500
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define SIZEOFINT 4

// Globals
int nreps;
int nbufs;
int newSd;

// Read all the data from the client and output how long it took
void readFromClient(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    cout << "readFromClient triggered!" << endl;

    // Declare data buffer
    char databuf[BUFSIZE];

    // Record start time
    struct timeval theTime;
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int startTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Keep reading until the buffer is full
    int nRead = 0;
    while((nRead += read(newSd, databuf, BUFSIZE - nRead)) < BUFSIZE)
    {
        cout << "nRead now: " << nRead << endl;
    }

    // For testing single byte read
    /*
    cout << "Reading a byte... " << endl;
    char bytebuf[1];
    read(newSd, bytebuf, 1);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
    */

    // Record finish time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int finishTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the receiving time
    int receiveTime = finishTime - startTime;

    // Display the receiving time
    cout << "data-receiving time = " << receiveTime << " usec" << endl;

    // Tell the client how much data was read
    cout << "Writing amount read... " << endl;
    write(newSd, (void*)nRead, SIZEOFINT);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Close the socket
    cout << "Closing socket... " << endl;
    close(newSd);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Store command line arguments
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nreps = atoi(argv[2]);
    int nbufs = atoi(argv[3]);

    // Declare a socket
    struct sockaddr_in acceptSockAddr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(acceptSockAddr);
    memset((char*)&acceptSockAddr, '\0', sizeof(acceptSockAddr));
    acceptSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Address Family Internet
    acceptSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    acceptSockAddr.sin_port = htons(port); // convert host byte-order

    // Open a stream-oriented socket
    int serverSd;
    if((serverSd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Signal OS to reuse this port once server closes
    const int on = 1;
    setsockopt(serverSd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&on, sizeof(int));

    // Bind socket to local address
    if(bind(serverSd, (sockaddr*)&acceptSockAddr, sizeof(acceptSockAddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Instruct OS to listen for up to 5 clients
    listen(serverSd, MAX_PENDING);

    // Set up signal handler for IO from client
    struct sigaction action;  
    memset(&action, '\0', sizeof(action));
    action.sa_sigaction = &readFromClient;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    //fcntl(newSd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO); // Fixes problem with si_fd
    if(sigaction(SIGIO, &action, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) // sleep forever
    {
        cout << "Waiting for client... " << endl;
        if((newSd = accept(serverSd, (struct sockaddr*)&acceptSockAddr, &len)) < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failure");
            //exit(1);
        }
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
        fcntl(newSd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
        fcntl(newSd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <sys/types.h>    // socket, bind
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket, bind, listen, inet_ntoa
#include <netinet/in.h>   // htonl, htons, inet_ntoa
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // inet_ntoa
#include <netdb.h>        // gethostbyname
#include <unistd.h>       // read, write, close
#include <string.h>       // bzero
#include <netinet/tcp.h>  // SO_REUSEADDR
#include <sys/uio.h>      // writev
#include <signal.h>       // sigaction
#include <sys/time.h>     // gettimeofday
#include <fcntl.h>        // fcntl
#include <iostream>       // cout

using namespace std;
#define BUFSIZE 1500
#define SIZEOFINT 4

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Store commmand line arguments
    int server_port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nreps = atoi(argv[2]);
    int nbufs = atoi(argv[3]);
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[4]);
    const char* server_name = argv[5];
    int testType = atoi(argv[6]);

    // Check to ensure proper buffer count/sizes
    if(nbufs * bufsize != BUFSIZE)
    {
        perror("nbufs times bufsize must equal BUFSIZE");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(testType < 1 || testType > 3)
    {
        perror("test type must be 1, 2, or 3");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create buffers
    char databuf[nbufs][bufsize];

    // Retrieve hostent structure
    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname(server_name);
    if(!host)
    {
        perror("unknown hostname");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Declare socket structure
    sockaddr_in sendSockAddr;
    memset((char*)&sendSockAddr, '\0', sizeof(sendSockAddr));
    sendSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Address Family Internet
    sendSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*host->h_addr_list));
    sendSockAddr.sin_port = htons(server_port);  // convert host byte-order

    // Open stream-oriented socket
    int clientSd;
    if((clientSd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failure");
        exit(1);
    };

    // Connect socket to server
    if(connect(clientSd, (struct sockaddr*)&sendSockAddr, sizeof(sendSockAddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failure");
        exit(1);
    };

    // Record start time
    struct timeval theTime;
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int startTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Conduct tests
    for(int i = 0; i < nreps; i++)
    {
        switch(testType)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                // Multiple write test
                cout << "Running multiple write test" << endl;
                for(int j = 0; j < nbufs; j++)
                {
                    cout << "Writing buffer " << j << "... " << endl;
                    write(clientSd, databuf[j], bufsize);
                    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
                }
                cout << "Finished multiple write test" << endl;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                // Vector write test
                cout << "Running vector write test" << endl;
                struct iovec vector[nbufs];
                for(int j = 0; j < nbufs; j++)
                {
                    vector[j].iov_base = databuf[j];
                    vector[j].iov_len = bufsize;
                }
                cout << "Writing vector... " << endl;
                writev(clientSd, vector, nbufs);
                cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
                cout << "Finished vector write test" << endl;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                // Single write test
                cout << "Running single write test" << endl;

                cout << "Writing... ";
                write(clientSd, databuf, nbufs * bufsize);
                cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

                // For testing single byte write
                /*
                cout << "writing a byte..." << endl;
                char singleByte[1];
                write(clientSd, singleByte, 1);
                cout << "wrote a byte!" << endl;
                */

                cout << "Finished single write test" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    // Record finish time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int finishTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the sending time
    int sendTime = finishTime - startTime;

    // Receive number of bytes read from server
    int nReads = 0;
    cout << "reading nReads from server... " << endl;
    read(clientSd, (void*)nReads, SIZEOFINT);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    // Record read time
    gettimeofday(&theTime, NULL);
    int readTime = theTime.tv_usec + theTime.tv_sec * 1000000;

    // Calculate the round-trip time
    int roundTime = readTime - startTime;

    // Display data sending statistics
    cout << "Test " << testType << ": data-sending time = " << sendTime;
    cout << " usec, round-trip time = " << roundTime << " usec, # reads = ";
    cout << nReads << endl;

    // Close the socket
    cout << "Closing the socket... " << endl;
    close(clientSd);
    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    cout << "Exiting!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are still severe problems when attempting to establish a second client connection to the server after closing the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be fcntl'ing the socket to F_SETOWN yourself as the controlling process and to SETFL the O_ASYNC flag, which causes the socket to actually send a signal to the SETOWN'd process group. If you don't do those things, no signals will be sent, regardless of whether you use signal(2) or sigaction(2)

Comment: I thought I was doing that inside the sleep loop?